# Android: Is it possible to change sensor reporting modes?

Tags: android, sensors

I am interested in using the significant motion sensor, but I realized that this is a one-shot reporting sensor. So after it reports an event once, it no longer reports anymore until I re-register the sensor.

My goal is to detect significant motion at all times, for example when a user picks up their phone, shakes it, throws it, etc... Based on that triggered event I will do something.

I'm wondering now if there is an alternative or a way to continuously listen for significant motion sensor events.

I honestly thought about just continuously re-registering the sensor but I think there are consequences to that approach and it's a hack.

Comment: "I'm wondering now if there is an alternative or a way to continuously listen for significant motion sensor events" -- if you are willing to modify the OS, there may be options. Given that this is a wakeup sensor, I assume the reason this is a one-shot sensor is to minimize power consumption and to serve as a nudge to developers that this is not the sort of thing to be used continuously.

Comment: For sure, you make a great point @CommonsWare, it will drain the battery hmm... There's also the option of Activity Recognition LIbrary which appears to offer similar results.